# To check values in datatable and add values to datatable

Tags: c#, asp.net

In the below code I have a static method in which I have a datatable with values and another empty datatable `Orderdbl` and add 3 columns.

Now my aim is to send `locationid,productid,quantity` to the static method.
Now I want to check `productid` in datatable `dtGrid` if it does not have the value, and it should check with another datatable `Orderdbl` if it doesnot have the value then add the values to datatable `Orderdbl` and store it in a session. Pls help me to this.

```
 [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
public static void InsertData(string LocationID, string ProductID, string Quantity)
{
   MastersClient objIndent = new MastersClient();
   DataTable dtGrid = (DataTable)HttpContext.Current.Session["VSOrderForm"];
   // DataSet ds = objIndent.CheckForExistingOrder(Int32.Parse(LocationID), ProductID);

   var DataCheck = dtGrid.Select("ProductID = '" + ProductID + "'");
   if (DataCheck.Length != 0)
   {
       // do something...
   }
    //if (ds != null && ds.Tables.Count > 0)
    //{
    //}
    else
    {
        DataTable Orderdbl = new DataTable();
        Orderdbl.Columns.Add("LocationID", typeof(string));
        Orderdbl.Columns.Add("ProductID", typeof(string));
        Orderdbl.Columns.Add("Quantity", typeof(string));
        DataRow row = Orderdbl.NewRow();
        //if (string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)Orderdbl.Rows[i][j].value))
        if (Orderdbl == null)
        {
            row["LocationID"] = LocationID;
            row["ProductID"] = ProductID;

            Orderdbl.Rows.Add(row);
            HttpContext.Current.Session["OrderForm"] = Orderdbl;
        }
        else
        {
            string FilterCond1 = "ProductID=" + ProductID;
            DataRow[] newrow = Orderdbl.Select(FilterCond1);
            if (newrow.Length > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < newrow.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (newrow[i]["ProductID"].ToString() == ProductID)
                    {
                        // YOUR CODE HERE 
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                row["LocationID"] = LocationID;
                row["ProductID"] = ProductID;

                Orderdbl.Rows.Add(row);
                HttpContext.Current.Session["OrderForm"] = Orderdbl;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry friend. No one here will write code for you. In case if you get any strange error or stuck with some issues, then people will help you with their ideas.

Comment: @Thangadurai i have written the code pls tell me were is the mistake

Comment: @Mairaj Ahmad first i am trying to store values in datatable and kept in session on next time on storing another value the datatable count is 0 i want to store all the values in datatable and store in session

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you want.First look in dtGrid table if value is not found will look in second datatable and if still not found than add new row

```
public static void InsertData(string LocationID, string ProductID, string Quantity)
{
    MastersClient objIndent = new MastersClient();
    DataTable dtGrid = (DataTable)HttpContext.Current.Session["VSOrderForm"];
    DataTable Orderdbl = (DataTable)HttpContext.Current.Session["OrderForm"];
    // DataSet ds = objIndent.CheckForExistingOrder(Int32.Parse(LocationID), ProductID);


    //Check in first table
    var DataCheck = dtGrid.Select("ProductID = '" + ProductID + "'");
    if (DataCheck.Length != 0)
    {
        // do something...
    }
    //if (ds != null && ds.Tables.Count > 0)
    //{
    //}
    else
    {
        //Not found in first now check in second talbe
        if (Orderdbl != null)
        {
            string FilterCond1 = "ProductID=" + ProductID;
            DataRow[] newrow = Orderdbl.Select(FilterCond1);
            //If Length > 0 it means found in second table,
            if (newrow.Length > 0)
            {

                for (int i = 0; i < newrow.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (newrow[i]["ProductID"].ToString() == ProductID)
                    {
                        // YOUR CODE HERE 
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //Not found in second talbe now add new row

                DataRow row = Orderdbl.NewRow();
                //if (string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)Orderdbl.Rows[i][j].value))
                row["LocationID"] = LocationID;
                row["ProductID"] = ProductID;
                Orderdbl.Rows.Add(row);
                HttpContext.Current.Session["OrderForm"] = Orderdbl;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //This will run first time when session has no value.
            Orderdbl = new DataTable();
            Orderdbl.Columns.Add("LocationID", typeof(string));
            Orderdbl.Columns.Add("ProductID", typeof(string));
            Orderdbl.Columns.Add("Quantity", typeof(string));
            DataRow row = Orderdbl.NewRow();
            //if (string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)Orderdbl.Rows[i][j].value))
            row["LocationID"] = LocationID;
            row["ProductID"] = ProductID;
            Orderdbl.Rows.Add(row);
            HttpContext.Current.Session["OrderForm"] = Orderdbl;
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: I want to check productid in datatable dtGrid if it does not have the value, and it should check with another datatable Orderdbl if it doesnot have the value then add the values to datatable Orderdbl and store it in a session

Comment: you have assigned value to Session["OrderForm"] and you are reading from Session["VSOrderForm"] is this right ?

Comment: I have to check both the session datatable by passing productid and store into Session["OrderForm"]

Comment: The datatable Orderdbl count is 0 every time on insertion Session["OrderForm"]

Comment: Updated answer now check it there was some issue in prevoius code.

Comment: On the second time it throws error A column named 'LocationID' already belongs to this DataTable.